# How to show all permalinks of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I want to show all current permalinks of my wordpress posts in just one page. I don't want to use archives. I use database to do this, but its showing only guid links.

Means I want to make list like this:

> http://www. mywebsite. com/category/post1
>   http://www. mywebsite. com/category/post1
>   http://www. mywebsite. com/category/post1

but what I am getting from database is:

> http://www. mywebsite. com/?p=1
>   http://www. mywebsite. com/?p=2
>   http://www. mywebsite. com/?p=3

Please help me

Comment: go to `admin/settings/permalink` and set

Comment: I already did this. Now I want to display all these paramalinks on different page. I just want to make a list of the current urls of my website

Comment: There is a plugin for this, called WP Sitemap Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php 
 $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ); 
 $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
 if( $loop->have_posts() ): 
     while( $loop->have_posts() ): 
         $loop->the_post(); 
         global $post; 
         echo get_permalink($post->ID);
     endwhile; 
 endif; 
 wp_reset_query();
?>
```

set your permalink settings to postname first.

Have fun :)

Comment: thats great! can you tell me how to store these urls into database.

Comment: @RameshPardhi  you don't need to store it again in DB. they are already stored in DB. why do you wanna duplicate ?

Comment: Where they are in database? I found only guid urls in database but I want to save these current paramalinks. I just want to do it...

Comment: You don't need to use SQL queries to get permalinks.There are different ways to do this with WP core functions. Just use above code to retrive it. Why do you need to store it again ?

Comment: Permalinks are handling by WP core. You don't need to worry about it

Comment: I got you... Thank You Dhanuka Nuwan

Comment: @RameshPardhi  Please accept my answer. That will be much appriciated.

Comment: Perfectly working. However you will have load the core of wordpress `require( 'YOURWEBSITE/wp-load.php' ) ;` and maybe adjust memory limit `ini_set('memory_limit',"512M");` if the query becomes too big.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your permalinks to custom structure with this '/%postname%/', without the quotes.

and then do something like this

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 268 ); ?>">My link to a post or page</a>
```

where 268 is your post id

Use the loop to get the post ids.
[http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts](http://get%20posts)

If you have moved your application recently, then make sure you have the permalinks settings tab opened and checked once.