# Where do you place test or experimental php code in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, testing

I have a Wordpress based website that I've been running for years. I recently had questions about permalinks. I came across some code that supposedly dumps a list of permalinks.

```
<?php 
 $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ); 
 $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
 if( $loop->have_posts() ): 
     while( $loop->have_posts() ): 
         $loop->the_post(); 
         global $post; 
         echo get_permalink($post->ID);
     endwhile; 
 endif; 
 wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The article doesn't say where to put that code or how to cause it to run. Where do I put it?  Should I insert it in public/index.php?  Does it run every time I ask for a page?

I tried putting the code in a regular content page but it just displays an incomplete version of the code.

For reference, the question is from:
[How to show all permalinks of wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274404/how-to-show-all-permalinks-of-wordpress/28274853#28274853)

Comment: If I’m understanding you correctly, a common place to test or try things is in a development environment, be it local or a non-public dev or staging server

Comment: However, your question could also just be “I found this code, how to I see id it would work for me”, and if that’s the case, that’s a different issue.

Comment: I've edited the question. I hope is is more meaningful.

To Chris: I have a live wordpress website that I've been running for years. I was hoping I could insert this code somewhere, run it, save the output, and then removed the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good time to familiarize yourself with the [WordPress template file hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

If you create a new page with a title of `Test123`, the page's slug will be, by default, `test123`. According to the hierarchy diagram, this means you can create a file called `page-test123.php` in your theme's root, put whatever PHP code you want in there, and it will run in a WordPress context.

So complete those steps and then put the following code into the PHP file:

```php
<?php
$args = ['post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1];
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo get_permalink($post->ID), '<br />';
}
```

This code is a modified version of what you posted that does what you originally tried, I've just simplified it.

Also, just to be very clear, this code goes into the PHP file, not the WordPress WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you, Chris. I could follow that and made it happen. I can see this being useful for other experiments and debugging in the future.